# Issues with selenium automated access to run otherwise open new windows or tabs

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

on the page,
I want open url in a new window of tab use driver.get(url) and processing completed will close the page and go back to the previous window.

1.If the entire process is completed in a window, after completion, there is no window that is open and cannot be operated.
2.But using js script

```
window.open ('url')
```

but it does n’t work, prompt:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=51483): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/1f2311de-3086-4a15-be02-e3d6d6308a58/element (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001758103C880>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] 由于目标计算机积极拒绝，无法连接。'))
```

ps:IE driver

Comment: I think we use driver.execute_script("window.open('url')") to target we do driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1]).

Comment: but js not work

Comment: Do you have requests.get(url) somewhere?

Comment: Use a try and catch and use timer.

Comment: @arundeepchohan no

Comment: @arundeepchohan which exception？

Comment: NewConnectionError , MaxRetryError and use a time.sleep(5)

Comment: @arundeepchohan  not use

Comment: pop up ‘command line server for IE driver stop work’

Comment: in these kind of cases i create new webdriver instance to handle a new window.
since selenium doesnt support easily switching windows/tabs.  

it's easy to handle multiple instances in the same process.

Comment: but I think some thing have in the driver，for example i just login